# jquery form submit is not working with different actions value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to submit my page using jquery with different actions, but below code seems not working

adding user

```
$("#createBtn").click(function() {
    $("#formname").submit(function(event){
        $(this).attr('action', 'addUser.html');
    });
});
```

updating user

```
$("#updateBtn").click(function() {
        $("#formname").submit(function(event){
                $(this).attr('action', 'updateUser.html');
            });
        });
```

EDIT :-

```
<form:form name="formname"  commandName="comandNamd">
```

i didnt give action name, since i want to change actions.

on click of button, the page is not getting submitted.

Comment: Are the buttons submit buttons contained in the form? And where on the page do you include your JavaScript?

Comment: yes buttons are inside the form, i have place my script inside the <script> tag in top of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"i have place my script inside the  tag in top of the page"*

In that case your script won't actually bind event handlers to your buttons, because the script will run before the form and buttons have been parsed. `$("#createBtn")` will find no matching element. You can correct this either by putting your script at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or by wrapping your code in a document ready handler.

Also, the code inside your `.click()` handler is binding a submit handler to the form, which doesn't really make sense. You just want to set the action:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#createBtn").click(function() {
        $("#formIdHere").attr('action', 'addUser.html');
        // OR
        $(this).closest("form").attr('action', 'addUser.html');
    });
    $("#updateBtn").click(function() {
        $("#formIdHere").attr('action', 'updateUser.html');
    });
});
```

You said in a comment that the "buttons are inside the form" - if they are submit buttons then the above code should work. The click will run the code shown to set the action, after which the default behaviour (form submission) will continue.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing submit handler inside the click handler. This should work.

```
$("#createBtn").click(function() {
    $("#formname").attr('action', 'addUser.html');
    $("#formname").submit();

});
```

Change for  update button also.

Comment: even i tried this, but not working!!!, i am using spring form tag, will that be a problem?

Comment: Can you check in the browsers console ? for which action its being submitted ?

Comment: it reloads the page on submit, instead of addUser.html action

Answer (score -1):

i have fixed the issue, and thanks for your help, since i am using spring form tag,

```
<form:form  name="formName" commandName="command">
```

but in jquery i was using above form name attribute value, but actually spring form tag generates form id value and final html looks like

```
<form:form id="formid" name="formName" commandName="command">
```

after changing the code to have formid, it worked thanks

```
$("#formid").attr('action', 'addUser.html');
```